# microsoft azure hosted database and firewalls

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am doing mobile development on Xcode and using hosted database from Microsoft Azure.

I noticed there is firewall settings on Microsoft Azure in order to add clients.

How will this work when the mobile app is deployed? Should all ports be opened on the database? Or do I need to use Web Services?

Comment: Not all ports. All originating IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How will this work when the mobile app is deployed? Should all ports
>   be opened on the database? Or do I need to use Web Services?

You should definitely **NOT** open all ports and direct connectivity to the database from mobile apps is strongly discouraged.

Recommended way would be to use some kind of service layer sitting between your mobile app and the database. All the requests from the app should go to this service layer which will perform database operations. This service layer could be deployed as [`Azure Mobile App Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/mobile/), [`Azure API App Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/) or a Web API hosted in [`Azure Web Apps Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/web/).

Comment: thank you Gaurav, what is the most popular method? Or which one of those four would you recommend?

Comment: Since you're building a mobile app, my recommendation would be to use Azure Mobile App Service as it is essentially MBaaS (Mobile Backend as a Service) offering from Azure. You get support for other things out of the box in this service which could be relevant to your app  (like push notifications etc.).